# Django show many to many relation in User model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
   images = ArrayField(models.TextField())
   user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='products')
```

how can I show that relation inside Admin Panel, so that when I go to User form inside Admin Panel I could see what products are related to that user.

Comment: can describe your problem statement in more detail

Comment: @prashant added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `ModelAdmin` class for your user model. In order to do so, you first "unregister" the one that is defined by Django, and then register a new `UserAdminWithProducts`.

For example:

```
# myapp/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.unregister(User)

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdminWithProducts(UserAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = UserAdmin.filter_horizontal + ('products',)
```

For more information see the [documentation on *The Django admin site* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#module-django.contrib.admin).

Comment: I created a new app and added that code but nothing happens

Comment: @KadiemAlqazzaz: did you add your app to the installed apps? Does the config load the admin file?

Comment: Yes, I added it to `INSTALLED_APPS` but what do you mean by `Does the config load the admin file?`, sorry but thats my first project in Django